# Multiple files in .NET Resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resources

You can have two resources files in visual studio resources with the same name, one of which is intended for test environments and the other for production environments?

Comment: What? I've googled a lot but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, depending on the "resource".

If you edit the application's resources in the Resources tab of the application's properties.  You can see that there is no way to add a flag for DEBUG or RELEASE.

If your resource is a file, then you *could* add two files to your project, one for DEBUG and the other for RELEASE, then in your application's pre-build event copy the right one over after adding that 3rd filename to your resources.

Comment: Side note: The fact that there is no UI to configure DEBUG/RELEASE difference does not mean one need to resort to pre/post-build steps for making conditional includes i.e. for `ItemGroup` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115696/conditional-content-based-upon-configuration ...