# Publish only minified versions of JavaScript files (ASPNET Core)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, publish, minify

Although there are several articles on this issue, I can't seem to find any that are recent and apply to **ASPNET Core 2.x**, Visual Studio 2017.

How do I only publish my minified versions of JavaScript (.js) files?

It would be nice to do this via the publish profile (.pubxml) so that I can include/exclude by setting up different publish profiles (Dev, UAT, Staging, Production.

Comment: there is MVc bundle, wont this work for you ?

Comment: If you are referring to creating a bundle of minified files, that doesn't solve the original .js file from being published...where anyone can view it by adjusting the URL.

Comment: I mean you could have two diffrent bundles, one On release and other on debugg, the same could also be applied with diffrent attr to. have a look at this, not sure if this is the answer your looking for though.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug

Comment: Sure, I can create two bundles, but it just seems so hacky.  I just don't know why you can't have something in your publish config that would help say, don't deploy these files.  That is my question.

Comment: This just doesn't appear possible, so I wrote a post build powershell that just deletes CSS and JavaScript files where a minified version exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just exclude all .css/.js files and then include .min files. The last rule overrides the previous.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*.css" CopyToPublishDirectory="never" />
   <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*.min.css" CopyToPublishDirectory="always" />
   <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*.js" CopyToPublishDirectory="never" />
   <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*.min.js" CopyToPublishDirectory="always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Appears to work and is super simple, and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Publish profiles are essentially project file overrides and use the same schema as project files. Microsoft supplies an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exclude-files

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot/content/**/*.txt" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Additionally, you can set any file in your project to be included or excluded based on build configuration directly in the project:
[Conditional Content Based Upon Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115696/conditional-content-based-upon-configuration)

Comment: I had tried something similar to this, without success. Because "Never" is used, I was negating my patterns to allow only min file versions. <Content Update="['!wwwroot/js/**/*.min.js','wwwroot/js/**/*.js']" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />

Comment: Ah, good point; did you try the Exclude attribute? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#use-the-exclude-attribute - 
<Compile Include="*.res" Exclude="Form1.cs">

Comment: Bottom line...publish doesn't support multiple globbing syntax, either by placing patterns in an array using [] or by just separating them with commas.  I've tried so many variables and nothing works.